# MAUI Limit Width of a Grid and Left Align on Windows

Tags: layout, grid, maui

I have a simple Grid layout below on the Windows platform:

```
    <Grid 
        RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" 
        MaximumWidthRequest="400" 
        BackgroundColor="Orange">
        
        <SearchBar 
            BackgroundColor="Pink" 
            Margin="4"  />
        
        <ListView 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            BackgroundColor="blue" 
            Margin="4">
            
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>ListView Item 1</x:String>
                    <x:String>ListView Item 2</x:String>
                    <x:String>ListView Item 3</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
        
        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="2">
            <Button Text="Cancel" Clicked="ContentPageButton_Clicked" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

What I'd like is for the width of the grid layout to be limited (1).  It just doesn't look right to me if the Grid layout fills the entire width of the window when in landscape orientation.  But I'd also like the Grid layout to shrink if the window width is less than that width limit (2).  Last, I'd also like for the Grid layout to be left aligned (3).

When I use the code above I get the Grid layout centered rather than left aligned.  The Grid layout width does shrink as the window shrinks below the 400 MaximumWidthRequest.

[image]

When I use a HorizontalStackLayout as a container or set HorizontalOptions="Start" on the Grid itself, the Grid layout shrinks to its minimum width.

[image]

When I set a WidthRequest, the Grid layout does not shrink.  In the screenshot below the SearchBar is clipped on the right side:

[image]

Can you think of any way to meet all 3 requirements above?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: what is the meaning of `layout`? Do you mean you want to adjust the width of the ListView cell?

Comment: Thank you @SeanHe-MSFT, I revised the question to be more specific... I mean the grid width with the ListView and SearchBar children following suit.

Comment: I added the `HorizontalOptions="Start"` in <Grid>', and then ran the code on the pixel5, when the pixel5 in portrait mode, the gird would fill the entire screen, and the SearchBar, ListView cell also filled the grid's width. In landscape mode, the grid's width did not change, the children control still filled the gird's width, and the gird kept left of the window. But I still cannot understand your demand, can you add any images to describe your demand?
But I still cannot understand your demand, do you mean you want to

Comment: Thank you for your help @SeanHe-MSFT I added screenshots and this is probably specific to the windows platform.

Comment: I changed the code in<Grid>: `<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" WidthRequest="800"BackgroundColor="Orange"HorizontalOptions="Start">`,Then the Grid width could be limited by `WidthRequest` and the Grid could be placed at the left of the window. If the search Bar was cliped, you can try to tug the edge of the window to expand the window size, or change its default size.